# how can i handle the jsp taglib by clicking event?

Tags: java, onclick, taglib

i have a form with one text input and submit button 
i wanna my taglib is run when submit button clicked
my taglib save the textbox value in a dataBase

i wtote below code but not run:

```
<form action="some page">

<input type="text" name="t1">
<input type="submit" oncick="<mytaglibName1: mytaglibNmae2> >

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you don't want JSP tags to store values, you want to return the form to a Servlet and then do the database storage in there...

```
<form action="servlets/StoreValue">

<input type="text" name="t1">
<input type="submit">

</form>
```

then in your Servlet you'd do the database storage. When your JSP page is returned to the web browser it doesn't contain any JSP tags, all the browser sees is HTML, you you have to submit the form back to the web server to do the processing.

I may of totally misunderstood the question in which case my apologies.